2 yr old place, removed vents and mold everywhere. How bad is this? How to fix?
I went to sand and paint the vents and found mold everywhere with clear signs it was painted over. How bad is this? Can I get some concrobium mold control stuff or something else and spray it all around all the vent opening and try to wipe off and paint some kilz paint spray on it? Is this stuff further into the ceiling? Do I need to call a professional?
There are signs of water damage at base of one of the kitchen cabinets peeling off from being wet or moist, another bathroom cabinet base like 20 ft away from kitchen and at the base of the hallway closet door. My guess is FL humidity from leaving porch open. But other than that I haven't found any mold below the ceiling. The AC air intake vent has no mold nor does anywhere in or around AC but it was replaced before place was bought.
Scroll for all pics of 3 vents removed, and 2 not yet removed: https://imgur.com/a/o0uFr9o
Update: took some better / closer pics of bathroom one: https://imgur.com/a/yuQJbwA

are you certain that it is mold?

If this is Fla. I believe what you think is mold is not the great killer of humanity that you believe it is. I live in Fla too. The humidity is almost always high and can instigate rust quickly, however what many do not know is the dust here in Fla can be super fine and black. It is not uncommon for the black dust from the sandy soil to get on everything and into the ductwork, where it finds a way to stick on surfaces and mimic mold. What you have posted pics of is not concerning at all to me. Clean it with whatever if you need to and move on.

Got it thanks. I put up some better pics just incase.

To identify anything as mold it will have to be tested.  In any case most of what I see is dirt on the texture splatter.   Being where air is often moving the area is not highly suitable to grow mold.  It is too dry.  If it makes you feel better clean it.  Unless you decide to lick it... and at that lick every little part of it it isn't an issue. Clean it and move on. Nothing there will kill you.

Thanks I'll put my mind at ease. If I'm feeling risky, I'll try the lick tests
